# How to create array with CSV file using header in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, csv

I try to create an array with CSV file and use the first row to be keys. In PHP.
My code is:

```
if (($handle = fopen($target_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $size = filesize($target_file);
    if(!$size) {
        echo "Empty file.<br/>";
        exit;
    }
    $csvcontent = array();
    $header = null;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        if($header === null) {
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }
        $csvcontent[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The final format is not exactly what I need.

Someone can help me to obtain better results?
If CSV file like this:

> id,fonction,hostname,domain
>   1,Elemental 6,MTLLXISNET06,local
>   2,Elemental 7,MTLLXISNET07,local
>   3,Crawl Manager,RDICRAWLMANAGER,local

I need a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [fonction] => Array
        (
            [0] => Elemental 6
            [1] => Elemental 7
            [2] => Crawl Manager
        )

    [hostname] => Array
        (
            [0] => MTLLXISNET06
            [1] => MTLLXISNET07
            [2] => RDICRAWLMANAGER
        )

    [domain] => Array
        (
            [0] => local
            [1] => local
            [2] => local
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a different approach than Suyog's good answer:

```
if (($handle = fopen($target_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $size = filesize($target_file);
    if(!$size) {
        echo "Empty file.<br/>";
        exit;
    }

    $header = false;
    $content = array();

    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        if (!$header) {
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }

        // $row will be 0=>1, 1=>Elemental 6, 2=>MTLLXISNET06, 3=>local
        // check if content has 0, 1, 2 and 3 keys
        // If not, create them and assign value as an array
        // If those key exist, push new value into the array
        foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $content)) {
                $content[$key] = array($value);
            } else {
                $temp = $content[$key];
                array_push($temp, $value);
                $content[$key] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }

    $final = array_combine($header, $content);
    print_r($final);

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [fonction] => Array
        (
            [0] => Elemental 6
            [1] => Elemental 7
            [2] => Crawl Manager
        )

    [hostname] => Array
        (
            [0] => MTLLXISNET06
            [1] => MTLLXISNET07
            [2] => RDICRAWLMANAGER
        )

    [domain] => Array
        (
            [0] => local
            [1] => local
            [2] => local
        )

)
```

Test example:

```
$ cat test.txt
id,fonction,hostname,domain
1,Elemental 6,MTLLXISNET06,local
2,Elemental 7,MTLLXISNET07,local
3,Crawl Manager,RDICRAWLMANAGER,local
```

Test code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('test.txt', 'r');

$header = false;
$content = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    if (!$header) {
        $header = $row;
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $content)) {
            $content[$key] = array($value);
        } else {
            $temp = $content[$key];
            array_push($temp, $value);
            $content[$key] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
$final = array_combine($header, $content);
print_r($final);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You can use this function as:

```
$tempArray = csv_to_array('myfile.csv');
```

Then some simple looping and manipulating the function result as follows will give the expected output:

```
$outArray = array();
foreach($tempArray as $temp)
    foreach($temp as $key => $val)
        $outArray[$key][] = $val; 

echo "<pre>"; print_r($outArray);
```

The result of this will be:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [fonction] => Array
        (
            [0] => Elemental 6
            [1] => Elemental 7
            [2] => Crawl Manager
        )

    [hostname] => Array
        (
            [0] => MTLLXISNET06
            [1] => MTLLXISNET07
            [2] => RDICRAWLMANAGER
        )

    [domain] => Array
        (
            [0] => local
            [1] => local
            [2] => local
        )

)
```

**[Function source](https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/385876)**